# Should walls be painted or flooring installed first?

Tags: basement, flooring, painting

I am finishing up the basement drywall. What should I do next, paint or the LVT flooring? I am looking to keep the floor clean of paint.

Comment: asking for opinions is not allowed here ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: You could paint first, not worrying about dripping paint on the subfloor, or you could install the floor first, then mask & put down drop cloths. _You_ do whichever works best for _you_. Asking for opinions is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There are many similar questions on this site. Please search.

Answer (score 3):

Paint walls -> install floor -> install baseboards -> caulk and paint baseboards.

I usually cut the baseboards, then prime and paint them outside, and install after the flooring is done. But painting them after installation is how I see others doing it.

Comment: I like your method, prime and paint baseboards and instal after flooring.  Only need some touch-up then.

Comment: It's preferable to paint before install, but they can be painted after too, if you install them with sufficient gap above the floor to slip newspaper beneath (which you should do anyway so that the floor can float).  You can paint—not too gloopy a layer!—and then pull the paper out.

Comment: The ones doing the addition did the cut and paint system.  They cheated by marking the pieces so they knew where they went back in place.